# Groovy Regex multiple matches

Tags: regex, groovy, matching

With the following string saved in variable "start":

```
user stuff here 5
user banana1 pswd 4 
user lemon2 pswd 5
mumbo jumbo 12333 3
user h3lp pswd 8
```

What regex will grab the three digits(4,5,8) after 'pswd' preceded by a random string and 'user'? New to groovy matching. I attempted this `(username.*secret).\d`

would ideally like to perform something like this, where the matches can then be accessed in an array

```
def pattern = ~/\S+er\b/
def matcher = "My code is groovier and better when I use Groovy there" =~ pattern
assert matcher[0..-1] == ["groovier", "better"]
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will definitely try it and tell you. THank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\buser\s+\S+\s+pswd\s+(\d+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0HTJTo/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `user` - a `user` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespaces (some word)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `pswd` - a `pswd` word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/aIfJMh):

```
String s = "user stuff here 5\nuser banana1 pswd 4\nuser lemon2 pswd 5\nmumbo jumbo 12333 3\nuser h3lp pswd 8"
def re = /\buser\s+\S+\s+pswd\s+(\d+)/
def res = (s =~ re).collect { it[1] }
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 8]
```